# Card slide animation in React JS

Tags: reactjs, animation, material-ui, carousel, fade

I'm trying to make a random card selector in react-js and I need to do something like this.


I got these images from this website: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ as you can see in "center mode" when you scroll down.

So when the page loads, it should slide through all the cards and randomly stop on one, almost like a carousel. I'm very unsure about how to make the animation work so that it infinitely animates the cards sliding left/right either way. I want the focused one to be a little bigger and the ones around it to be slightly smaller as seen in the image.

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: Oops I just realized none of my images are displayed here.

Comment: this is the npm module . you can find example on this link . https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick

Comment: Vyas That is pretty helpful, I'll take a look, thanks!